# Windows 10 1803 OpenSSH named pipe forwaring

Tags: windows-10, ssh, openssh, forwarding

If I set `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` on Windows to a named pipe implementing the `ssh-agent` protocol it works as intended. Moreover, if I add `ForwardAgent yes` to my config file, I can use the local `ssh-agent` on the remote machine.

What is not working is adding `RemoteForward /home/ubuntu/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent //./pipe/ssh-pageant` to my config file. I get this error:

```
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype forwarded-streamlocal@openssh.com rchan 3 win 2097152 max 32768
debug1: client_request_forwarded_streamlocal: /home/ubuntu/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh
debug1: connect_next: host //./pipe/ssh-pageant ([unix]://./pipe/ssh-pageant) in progress, fd=8
debug1: channel 1: new [forwarded-streamlocal]
debug1: confirm forwarded-streamlocal@openssh.com
getsockopt SO_ERROR failed
debug1: channel 1: connection failed: Not a socket
connect_to //./pipe/ssh-pageant port -2: failed.
debug1: channel 1: free: forwarded-streamlocal, nchannels 2
```

Is possible to forward a Windows named pipe to a Linux host using Windows 10 1803 native OpenSSH?

Answer (score -1):

I found https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/435,
which shows that what you want to do is not supported as of now.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.